# Disable ios from changing GUI controller position by localization

Tags: ios, localization, uibutton, uilabel, constraints

I have a problem that the position of a button \ image is changed according to the language localization.

e.g. in Hebrew the alignment is right-to-left in opposite to English.
this causes the buttons \ images to be positioned on the other side of the screen, in oppose to English position.

how do I disable ios from re-positioning the buttons (according to localization)?

Comment: can u post a few reference screenshots of same screens in 2 languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple way for doing this:

go to the controller you want to fix it's position, and select it's constraints.

set **Direction** property to "**Left to Right**" instead of Leading to Trailing".

[image]

Comment: You are right. We can your constraint for it. But what if there are more UI on the screen and need mode modifications. Does constraint solve all the problems??

Answer (score 1):

How many languages are there for localization in your application?

If you think that there are more problems in UI then create separate .xibs file for separate localization.

Please check the link. This will help you.

https://www.clairereynaud.net/blog/getting-your-iphone-app-ready-for-localization/

Comment: there are 2 languages (He\En).

Comment: Then it will be easy for you to maintain the two xibs for each language. This will separate your UI according to the language and will be helpful to you in future for next modification if there any.

Comment: I didn't use xibs, but Thanks, I've got it :)

Comment: What you got?? tell us. so that we can upgrade our knowledge